# Solving a differential equation for specific values of independent variable

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have the following equations:

```
g1'[m]=1/6*g1[m]^2

gt'[m]=1/6*gt[m]^2+1/16*g1[m]^2
```

where the range of $m$ is given by $\{m,10,10^6\}$.

I want to find for which values of `m` have `gt'[m]==0`.

I also have the initial values:`{m,10,10^6}`

```
g1[10]==0.4

gt[10]==1.1
```

How do i solve such an equation, meaning

```
gt'[m]==0
```

to determine `m`?
Yes, to determine m.

Comment: Is this about the software Mathematica or is this a Mathematics question? If the latter, then [`this`](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is the appropriate site.

Comment: I mean with Mathematica software, is there a way of solving such an equation, within Mathematica language: F'[x]==0, x==?

Comment: $f'(x)=0$ is a differential equation which you can solve in order to determine $f(x)$ analytically. Yes, there is a command that gives you the solution for $f(x)$. It's called [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html). You should have phrased your question a bit better in my opinion. You don't solve for $x$.

Comment: Yes,ok. I am working in a physics problem where i have a so called "beta function", it has the form g'[m]=Functions of m, and i want to find for what values of m (energy) it vanishes, meaning the values for which the slope , the gradient vanishes. The DSolve, i think, doesn't help (as far as i know). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually in Quantum Field Theory, when we write the equations for the $\beta$-function, we know or can get the answer in terms of local d.o.f (colors) or global d.o.f (flavors). And usually that's how we draw phase diagrams, that demonstrate conformal windows, $\chi SB$ phases, and so on. I am not sure about the details of your studies and hence cannot offer further help. Sorry. Maybe you could make a post with the exact equation, give some context so you can get some help...

Comment: The initial values are positive, the derivatives are nonnegative, so both will increase and `gt'[m] == 0` never happens. Otherwise, one could solve such an equation like this: `Reap[NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[y'[t] == 0, Sow[t]]}, {}, {t, 0, 100}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]][[2, 1]]` -- The `"Residual"` method is needed so that `y'[t]` is a state variable (unfortunately). If that needs to be avoided, then it's more complicated than I can address here.

Comment: In order to solve for  gt'[m]>0, I would solve the first for gl, then substitute gl into the second, solve for gt, plot gt just to see what it looks like, then take the derivative of gt, plot it, and then use NSolve[D[gt[m],m]==a,m] or maybe FindRoot if I have a neighborhood of solution.